# Use "module load" as root on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I have a series of tools that I load into my workspace using "module load 'tool
". However, if I try and run this command as root (or just using sudo), I get "module:command not found". None of the module package commands are available. Is there a way to get this to work? I just need to run once to set up a tool with cuda.

Comment: `module` is not a standard command. What do you mean by “module package commands”? Are these supposed to be shell commands, or commands for something else? What are you trying to do?

Comment: "module load" comes form environment-modules package (http://modules.sourceforge.net/). It lets people package programs into "modules" and then you can load them, use them and unload them across multiple environments easily. It's pretty common in computational fields as far as I know - I'm in Comp Chem. I I have installed the package on my machine and I can call all of the routines in the module package from my regular user account, but I can't invoke them from root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the file path to the `sudo` path.

Run the command `sudo visudo`

you will see a line like this:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$
```

Now add the path of your command here and this should work.

For example:

```
$ sudo storm
sudo: storm: command not found
```

Now add the path as above:

```
$ sudo visudo 

secure_path="......:/opt/storm/bin"
```

save and exit.

now `sudo storm` will just work normally.

Note You should also add the path to the default path in /etc/profile.